# Save log of all the web access from my computer

Tags: python, url, logging, browser-history

I want to write a program that logs all of my web history(all URLs I visit).

I prefer to write a python script, but wonder if it is the best option. Is there a better way, maybe java or C++?

I have searched for API's to get the URL history but I didn't like those ways [like getting the address from the window title]. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Are you willing to proxy all of your requests?  Or are you wanting to either sniff the traffic or intercept it some other method?  The two latter options are going to be quite a bit more difficult than the first.  If you were willing to proxy it all, you could just use one of the many HTTP proxies out there that have logging capabilities.

Comment: I prefer the sniffing method, it's also fine to take this data from the history of the browsers or something like that. I know that something that really sniff like wireshark will be more difficult.thank's for the help.